# Seeking a better way to check an instance property and assign value depending on property type

Tags: python, introspection, praw

I'm working with the praw module, and I find that my objects sometimes have a property `subreddit` that is sometimes a string and that is sometimes an object with its own properties. I've dealt with it using the following:

```
for c in comments:
    if isinstance(c.subreddit, str):
        subreddit_name = c.subreddit
    else:
        subreddit_name =  c.subreddit.display_name
```

I have two functions where I have to do this, and it's really ugly. Is there a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) rather than [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl):

```
for c in comments:
    try:
         subreddit_name =  c.subreddit.display_name
    except AttributeError:
        subreddit_name = c.subreddit
```

You could also try [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), which takes a default like `dict.get`:

```
subreddit_name = getattr(c.subreddit, 'display_name', c.subreddit)
```

This is effectively a neater version of:

```
subreddit_name = (c.subreddit.display_name 
                  if hasattr(c.subreddit, 'display_name') 
                  else c.subreddit)
```

Comment: I will try getattr, didn't know you could supply a default. Thanks for the handy acronyms.